# Mongodb query working fine in console but not working in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have issue to run mongodb query in php language while its working fine and return result in console but when I try to implement in PHP language it return blank array.

Please let me know what could be issue?

**Below query is Working fine in console**

```
db.mp_ms_details.find({
    $or : [ 
        {"title": /.*पंचायत*/},
        {"description": /.*पंचायत*/}
    ]       
})
```

**Mongodb Query with PHP**

```
         $cursor = $collection->find(array('$or' => array(
              array("title" => "/.*पंचायत*/"),
              array("description" => "/.*पंचायत*/")
            )));
            $response = $cursor->toArray();
            echo count($response);die;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are running directly in MongoDB, you are using regex expression :

```
{"title": /.*पंचायत*/}
```

See, there are **no quotes** in the value field. But when you are running this through PHP, you are providing a String value :

```
array("title" => "/.*पंचायत*/")
```

So in the first query, you are looking for documents where title field contains (and not equals) पंचायत, while in the second query you are looking for documents having the exact title "/.*पंचायत*/"

For your use case:

```
array("title" => new MongoRegex("/.*पंचायत*/i"))
```

Comment: @rajaj,Can you please help me by writing a little query?

Comment: ,$where = array('description' => array('$regex' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex("पंचाय")));
                        $cursor = $collection->find($where);  this is working fine but how can I search for two column?

Comment: just like you added 'description' in array, add 'title' as well. Its an ARRAY